MySQL Ubuntu 24.04 LTS ERROR Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service"
Visual Studio Code crashes after pushing code to remote repository
Hello everyone! I recently started using Linux and decided to use Ubuntu 24.04.01 LTS I've noticed that it has given me some problems and such, but I've been able to adapt to most of them and I've managed to solve them.
But getting to the point, I've been using Visual Studio Code along with Git so that I can upload my local repositories to my remote repository on GitHub using the Git Bash terminal.
But every time I do 'Git Push' Visual Studio proceeds to freeze and then crash (forces the program to close). And when I try to reopen it after forcing it to close, the program repeats the same thing, freezes and closes.
I would appreciate if someone could give me a solution to this. I thought it might be due to some incompatibility of Visual Studio with Ubuntu 24.04.01 LTS. But honestly I'm new to Linux and I have no idea about the subject.
